# jButton 2nd image when pressed image doesnt change

Tags: java, swing

i have a set of buttons, when pressed some buttons are disabled. the buttons have their respective icons. however, what troubles me is when i click the btnAdd, the buttons are disabled and the image for btnAdd doesnt change. i am using Java Netbeans 8.0.2 and i am connected to MySql.

i am asking how am i going to make the btnAdd handle the second image when actionperform has taken place

here is the code

```
if(btnAdd.getText().equals("Add")){
btnAdd.setText("Save");
        btnDelete.setEnabled(true);
            btnEdit.setEnabled(false);
                btnExit.setEnabled(false);
                    btnSwitch.setEnabled(false);
                        btnCancel.setEnabled(true);
}else{
    btnAdd.setText("Add");
            btnAdd.setEnabled(true); 
                btnEdit.setEnabled(true);
                    btnDelete.setEnabled(true); 
                        btnSwitch.setEnabled(true);
                            btnCancel.setEnabled(false);
                                btnExit.setEnabled(true);
```

}

Comment: For better help, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We don't want to see your whole program, but rather you should condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles, has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Also, why should any **image** change? I don't see a call to `setIcon(...)` anywhere.

Comment: for the change image, my adviser wants to see the CRUD in my system. the buttons are for the CRUD action. this is a requirement in my case study.

Comment: Your code will not compile nor run for us, so it does not allow us to see where your error might be. Please re-read the [mcve link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Regarding your CRUD statement above, you do know that a JButton Icon will only change if you call `setIcon(...)` on the JButton and pass in the new Icon, right? Again, I see no explicit calls to this method in your posted code.

Comment: ok i'll re-write my code. i am asking for some patience. i'll be back

Comment: i am asking how am i going to make the btnAdd handle the second image when actionperform has taken place?

Comment: Then call `setIcon(newImageIcon)` on the JButton whose image you wish to change.

Comment: See edit to answer for example and for a minimal example program example as well.

Answer (score 2):

> i am asking how am i going to make the btnAdd handle the second image when actionperform has taken place?

In that case the solution is as per my comment -- call `setIcon(newImageIcon)` on the JButton whose image you wish to change. If your button uses an Action, you could also change the Action's `LARGE_ICON_KEY` property via the `putValue(LARGE_ICON_KEY, newImageIcon)`.

For example:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MultipleButtons extends JPanel {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   private JButton btnSaveAdd = new JButton();
   private JButton btnDelete = new JButton("Delete");
   private JButton btnEdit = new JButton("Edit");
   private JButton btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
   private JButton btnSwitch = new JButton("Switch");
   private JButton btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
   private JButton[] btns = {btnSaveAdd, btnDelete, btnEdit, btnExit, btnSwitch, btnCancel};

   public MultipleButtons() {
      Icon saveIcon = UIManager.getIcon("FileView.floppyDriveIcon");

      // wouldn't really use this icon but just used as an example
      Icon addIcon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.warningIcon");

      SaveAction saveAction = new SaveAction("Save", saveIcon);
      AddAction addAction = new AddAction("Add", addIcon);

      saveAction.setNextAction(addAction);
      addAction.setNextAction(saveAction);

      saveAction.buttonMapPut(btnDelete, true);
      saveAction.buttonMapPut(btnEdit, true);
      saveAction.buttonMapPut(btnExit, true);
      saveAction.buttonMapPut(btnSwitch, true);
      saveAction.buttonMapPut(btnCancel, false);

      addAction.buttonMapPut(btnDelete, true);
      addAction.buttonMapPut(btnEdit, false);
      addAction.buttonMapPut(btnExit, false);
      addAction.buttonMapPut(btnSwitch, false);
      addAction.buttonMapPut(btnCancel, true);

      btnSaveAdd.setAction(addAction);

      setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
      setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 5, 5));
      for (JButton jButton : btns) {
         add(jButton);
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      MultipleButtons mainPanel = new MultipleButtons();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("MultipleButtons");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

// parent class for both SaveAction and AddAction
abstract class SaveAddAction extends AbstractAction {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   private Map<AbstractButton, Boolean> buttonMap = new HashMap<>(); 
   private Action nextAction; // swap to this Action

   public SaveAddAction(String name, Icon icon) {
      super(name, icon);
      int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
      putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
   }

   public void buttonMapPut(AbstractButton key, Boolean value) {
      buttonMap.put(key, value);
   }

   public void setNextAction(Action nextAction) {
      this.nextAction = nextAction;
   }

   public void setButtonsEnabled(ActionEvent e) {
      AbstractButton source = (AbstractButton) e.getSource();
      if (nextAction != null) {
         source.setAction(nextAction);
      }
      for (AbstractButton button : buttonMap.keySet()) {
         button.setEnabled(buttonMap.get(button));
      }
   }
}

class AddAction extends SaveAddAction {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   public AddAction(String name, Icon icon) {
      super(name, icon);
   }

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      setButtonsEnabled(e);
      // TODO: code for adding goes here
   }

}

class SaveAction extends SaveAddAction {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   public SaveAction(String name, Icon icon) {
      super(name, icon);
   }

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      setButtonsEnabled(e);
      // TODO: code for saving goes here
   }

}
```